# How to call Windows APIs from JScript or Testcomplete?

Tags: javascript, winapi, pinvoke, testcomplete

How do I call Windows APIs or the functions that are defined in DLLs (Like user32, Kernel32 etc..) from JScript?

if there is any testcomplete based solution exists also fine for me.

For eg. How to proceed If I want to call [SHGetSpecialFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762204%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from JScript or jscript using testcomplete?

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly.

From IE, you can't at all.

With WSH - you could expose a COM object that calls the API for you.

Comment: Not from IE. But from a standalone script.